# How to group an array based on inner array keys in PHP?

Tags: php

I have an array which consists of statistics pulled from my database. Each inner array has a key based on where it come from. I want to group all these together in a new array.

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    7 => 
    array (
      'y' => 83,
      'label' => '2019-01-04 00:00:00',
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    7 => 
    array (
      'y' => 80,
      'label' => '2019-01-02 00:00:00',
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    8 => 
    array (
      'y' => 50,
      'label' => '2019-01-03 00:00:00',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Would look like this:

```
array (
    0 =>
    array( 
        0 =>
        array(
            'y' => 83,
            'label' => '2019-01-04 00:00:00',
        ),
        1 =>
        array(
            'y' => 80,
            'label' => '2019-01-02 00:00:00',
        ),
    ),
    1 =>
    array(
        0 =>
        array(
            'y' => 50,
            'label' => '2019-01-03 00:00:00',
        ),
    ),
)
```

However, I cannot seem to use `array_values()` to achieve this. I want to group all of the 7's into an array and all of the 8's into an array however, I could have more numeric keys in the future.

Is there a function I can use to do this?

Comment: Why do you want the keys to become 0 for 7 and 1 for 8? Why not just keep 7 and 8?

Comment: Because I am `json_encode` ing the data and the graph API I am using expects no keys in the array @trincot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your input is in variable `$data`, you could do this:

```
$result = [];
foreach($data as $arr) {
    foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
        $result[$k][] = $v;
    }
}
```

This will maintain the original inner-key value, so for your example input the result will have keys 7 and 8, not 0 and 1.

If you want that, then do one thing extra:

```
$result = array_values($result);
```

Comment: You, my friend, are my hero! Thank you so much! I'll accept when I can - this worked so perfectly and has saved me another n hours of frustration!

Comment: @rev, indeed, but I found the OP's *"...I could have more numeric keys..."* open for interpretation so I thought "better be safe than sorry".

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try!

```
<?php
$array = 
array(
    0 => array (
        7 => array (
            'y' => 83,
            'label' => '2019-01-04 00:00:00'
        )
    ),
    1 => array (
        7 => array (
            'y' => 80,
            'label' => '2019-01-02 00:00:00'
        )
    ),
    2 => array (
        8 => array (
            'y' => 50,
            'label' => '2019-01-03 00:00:00'
        )
    )
);

$sorted = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value)
    $sorted[key($value)][] = $array[$key][key($value)];

print_r($sorted);
```